# System of ODEs in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I am not sure how to implement the following system of ODEs as a single function on Matlab:

dy/dt = y(t) - y(t)x(t)

dx/dt = -x(t) + y(t)x(t)

Any help would be much appreciated as been stuck on this part of my overall problem for ages. Thanks

Comment: [Choose an ODE Solver: Systems of ODEs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html#bu3l4nx-1).

Comment: Thanks Troy, was helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to defining the constants to use, it should look like this:

```
function dzdt = odefunc(t,z) 
    x = z(1); y=z(2);
    dzdt = [ -x + x*y;  y - x*y ];
end

T, Z = ode45(odefunc, [T0  Tf], [ x0; y0 ])
```

As

```
F(x,y) = x+log(1/x) + y+log(1/y)
```

is a first integral with bounded level sets, the solutions will stay bounded (and are periodic) for positive initial values `x0,y0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not versed in the command line tools to create and simulate ODEs, then just use Simulink and then try to manipulate models from command line via `lsim` and then finally try to create the models in m files.

Here is a 2-minute exercise in simulink which allows you to choose whichever solver you like from a dropdown list.

[image]